# jupyter notebook のサーバーで、一定期間操作がなかった notebook を自動で shutdown したい

Tags: jupyter-notebook

分析タスクを行うために、 jupyter notebook を社内に対してサーバー上で公開しようとしています。

メモリは有限なので、ある一定時間操作がなかった notebook については、自動的にシャットダウンしてくれたらよいな、と思いました。

#### 質問

- jupyter notebook を走らせているサーバーがあるときに、ある一定時間操作がない notebook を shutdown するような設定・手法・ツールなどは存在しますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter notebook の設定に、 MappingKernelManager.cull_idle_timeout (一定時間活動していないカーネルを落とす) というオプションがあります。

参照 https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

このコマンドでできた ~/.jupyter フォルダ内の jupyter_notebook_config.py の該当欄のコメントアウトを消して、適当な値 (秒) を入れて再起動します。